# Is there evidence that heterosexual males make 'romantic advances' more often than heterosexual females?

Tags: reference-request, sexuality

Background: I have constructed a game theoretic model of romantic advances. There are a number of Nash equilibria in this model, distinguished by the frequency with which each sex makes romantic advances. I wish to know which equilibrium (if any) might be an accurate description of reality.

Initial research: I've found it surprisingly difficult to find studies of the sort I'm, after. Thus far I have found:

Article in psychology today, with a study showing that men are more likely to have asked for a first date in the last year, and less likely to have received a request for a first date than women - https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-how-and-why-sex-differences/201104/why-dont-women-ask-men-out-first-dates

Data from dating site OKCupid, showing that men send out first messages at roughly 3.5 times the rate that women do - https://www.okcupid.com/deep-end/a-womans-advantage

Question: Does anyone know of any further, 'stronger' studies indicating whether one sex makes romantic advances more frequently than the other? By 'romantic advances' here, I have in mind asking for first dates, requesting contact details, initiating first kiss, initiating first sexual contact, etc.

Comment: This questions sounds very similar as your previous [question about sexual selectivity](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/15212/11318). Could you explain how this one is different?

Comment: Yes. Previously I wished to know if one sex was more selective than the other. Now I wish to know if one sex makes more romantic advances than the other. I don't think one necessarily implies the other.

Comment: There is a strong cultural component to this question, relating to traditional role patterns of the sexes. If either sex considers particular behavior to be part of what is expected of their role, it is what they will demonstrate. In most cultures, women are "supposed to" be passive (i.e. wait for men to make the first move) while men are "supposed to" be active.